# Real world mongo query/updates per second

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am currently using mongo in production and have been happy with it so far.  I'm just trying to get a better understanding of how I might increase my throughput.  There could be a core gap in my understanding and I am trying to fill that.

I currently have a dataset that is relatively small ( less than 5M documents).  As a part of my application I have to rotate the data daily which means I will make somewhere between 1M and 5M inserts into the collection and roll off the old data.  I am able to do this pretty easily using two collections where one is a sandbox collection where the new data is pumped into and when done, I rename it to the 'live' collection so that it is quite fast and I dont have to wait for a remove() to finish.

My current issue is that on my server which is a quad core linux box with 16gb of ram I am unable to exceed ~2k updates per second on my data.  After I insert all my data (1M+) I have various post processes that read and then update the records.  The process functionally works fine, but no matter what I try I can not get higher than 4K (reads+writes) a second.

I have pruned the indexes on the collection to just a few single field indexes that I need and I have tried various things such as spooling up a ec2 mediumxlarge instance with a single esb ssd and I get the same results.  I have also tried forking the worker processes that read/update the data and no matter how many workers I put on it, the max number of ops doesnt really move.

Also, my post process is running on the same box as the mongo server so there is no network latency etc at play here. When the post process is running, the cpu is relatively quiet and may spike around 50% occasionally.  I also notice during this process I have a high lock % but I am guessing that is merely because I am issuing so many updates to the collection.  During my post process the lock % statys at 80+%.

My avg document size is ~1.4k.  There are 6 field level indexes on the collection. A typical post process (using node) would be to stream all documents with field x = y, update a different field on that record and then save it. In the process there would be some computations occurring. At first I thought my computations were the bottleneck so to solve for that I am forking multiple (4) node child processes and each child process does not exceed 40ish percent cpu. I'm pretty confident that my application is fine.  If I use 1 or 4 node processes it takes me roughly 20 minutes to work through the 1M documents.

Comment: We might be able to give more advice if you showed us your document structure and the operations on it.

Comment: I added more detail about doc size etc. Hope that helps!

Comment: I think you may just have contention for the database lock. Saying more helpful things would require a lot more information - like some output from mongostat, and example document, examples of the actual operations you're doing (or code for it).

Comment: Thanks for the help.. I think you are right.  I actually am moving to using the bulk process of mongo and getting better results.  I'm seeing consistently 3k updates a second using the bulk api... so I'll work with that for now.

Comment: Also, with the bulk api when I remove the indexes - I am seeing much much better numbers: 10k+ updates per second.

Comment: Great! Bulk inserts will really speed things up over one round trip per operation.

Answer (score 2):

Not much you can do, mongodb locks the entire collection when you are updating a single document in it. So the reads are blocked during the update.

[Version 3.0](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/announcing-mongodb-30) is supposed to improve this by introducing document level locking with the WiredTiger storage engine.

Comment: I dont think this is my issue though as I have also run mongo 3.0rc8 in a docker container as well as tried tokumx which has document level locking and am getting roughly the same results.

Comment: The default installation of mongodb 3.0 uses mmap storage engine did you use wiredtiger?

Comment: I did  not change the storage engine.. good catch. However, I did the same tests with tokumx which also has doc level locking.